# Do event listeners work like returned inner functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting familiar with closures in javascript [thanks to this fantastic stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). I noticed that if I have the following code:

```
function main(){
  var a = 5;
  var b = 5;
  inner();

  function inner(){
      $('#btn').on('click', function(){
         alert(a + b);
      });
   }
}
```

Any time the button is clicked on 10 will be alerted. However, unlike the examples in that stackoverflow answer the inner function isn't returned.

Do event listeners like the one I gave in the example remember their scope just like returned inner functions of closures?

Comment: Yes, to put it simply: all functions remember the scope they were declared in.

Comment: That's awesome, javascript is so cool!

Comment: It has nothing to do with returning the function. It's just a matter of creating the function and keeping a reference to it after the containing function returns. In this case, the reference is saved by `.on()` in the event listener.

Comment: The only thing in a function that can change depending on the context is `this`.

Comment: that's a deep misunderstanding, there's no a+b alert there anymore, that's alert(10) straight.

Comment: @BekimBacaj No, that really is `alert( a + b );`. Interpreter optimzation aside, every time `#btn` is clicked `a + b` will be reevaluated.

Comment: but that's not true at all

Comment: @BekimBacaj can you elaborate? I'm confused.

Comment: everything gets resolved before being actually run.

Comment: What if I have instead of `a = 5` I have `a = $('#textInput').val()`, then would a always be the initial value in said text input, or would it get the input's value each time the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, exactly. if `a = $('#textInput').val()` is defined in the enclosing function where `a` and `b` are originally assigned - from there on, that click should and will return only the initial value e.g.: the existing value assigned during the parse time. This means that in reality a "closure" is wrong interpretation over an insufficient understanding of JavaScript, or to be quite honest, a buzzword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closure doesn't have to be returned, any mechanism that gets a reference to it outside the containing function will save the environment with it. So instead of returning the function you could assign it to a global variable, e.g.

```js
var fun;

function main() {
  var a = 5;
  var b = 5;
  fun = function() {
    alert(a + b);
  };
}
main();
fun();
```

An event listener is just a global data structure associated with the DOM element, and the closure works the same way with that.

Comment: Ok that last sentence explains things for me. I wasn't sure how the inner workings of event listeners allowed it to remember the scope it was initialized in. I guess it's a globally scoped construct.

Comment: What else could it be, since it has to continue to exist after `addEventListener()` returns?

Comment: The DOM is a global data structure.